# Diigo Browser Extension/Addon to search your bookmarks?

Tags: browser-addons

I'm a [Del.icio.us](http://del.icio.us/) guy who migrated to [Diigo](http://diigo.com) when I was told of their ever-pending-untimely-demise.  It reminds me of a furniture store's going out of business sale.

Anyway, I've successfully migrated my bookmarks out of [Del.icio.us](http://del.icio.us/) and into [Diigo](http://diigo.com).  But there's something missing....I miss the sidebar popout toolbar of my [del.icio.us](http://www.delicious.com/help/quicktour/firefox) browser extension.  It allowed me to search my tags quickly and easily and I didn't have to go visit some [Diigo.com](http://diigo.com) just to accomplish this simple feat.  I could just click a button, or press CTRL-B and it would magically appear in my browsers sidebar.

See image here:

[image: del.icio.us sidebar a thing of beauty]

Now I was just wondering if there isn't the same thing that would have a tag-filtering mechanism for [Diigo.com](http://diigo.com) considering they have an api for it and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh hello...here's the answer: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-reasons-diigo-tastes-better-than-delicious/

The add-on (for Firefox at least) lives here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/diigo-web-highlighter-and-stic/